# Plus one, why wrong answer?

Tags: c++

> The correct situation is that change line.17 to "if (one >0)",
>   but I don't understand why it wrong when I use "if (one =1)",
>   when input is 0, the one is 0 how output become [1,1].

```
class Solution {
public:
    /**
     * @param digits a number represented as an array of digits
     * @return the result
     */
    vector<int> plusOne(vector<int>& digits) {
        // Write your code here
        vector<int> res(digits.size(), 0);
            int sum = 0;
            int one = 1;
            for (int i= digits.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                sum = one + digits[i];
                one = sum / 10;
                res[i] = sum % 10;
            }
            ***if (one = 1) {***
            res.insert(res.begin(), one);
            }
            return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: Input is [0].  output is [1,1].  expect is [1]

Comment: You may want to brush up on some basic language concepts.  `=` is assignment.  `==` is comparison.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm sure yzb knows the concepts

Comment: enable all warnings, surely the compiler will show you something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator it always returns the value assigned.
Therefore the condition will be always true for the assignment of non-zero values, in this case `1`.
Use the `==` operator if you are looking for equality check.

Answer (score 1):

`"="` is an assignment operator in c and c++. You need a Comparison operator to do comparison in your code and for that you need to use `"=="`.

Answer (score 0):

`if (one == 1) {`

not

`if (one = 1) {`

I think `if (one > 0` is better stylistically in any case.